# Overlying View with Opacity on top of ImageView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Currently I have a layout xml file where I bind many views. Here I am facing a problem. The problem is I can not overlay a **view** on an **(heart image)Imageview**. In layout **xml** file I can set but I can not overlay the **view** on that **imageview**.Please help me to figure our.I want the Black Opacity view on the Heart Imageview.

[image: Currently the problem of lying view on Imageview with Opacity]

Here is the xmlsource codes. I have marked the important codes with *.

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/listlayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/datalist"
            style="@style/listview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="#F18EA4"
        android:gravity="bottom" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/income_entry_container"
            style="@style/LightYellow"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:gravity="left|center"
            android:text="@string/confirm_income" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/expense"
            style="@style/LightYellow"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/income_entry_container"
            android:gravity="left|center"
            android:text="@string/confirm_expense" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/confirm_income_item_TextView"
            style="@style/LightYellow"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/expense"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/income_entry_container"
            android:gravity="right|center"
            android:text="@string/confrim_income_item" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/confirm_expense_item_TextView"
            style="@style/LightYellow"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/confirm_income_item_TextView"
            android:layout_below="@+id/confirm_income_item_TextView"
            android:gravity="right|center"
            android:text="@string/confirm_expense_item" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/confirm_income_amount_TextView"
            style="@style/LightYellow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:gravity="right|center"
            android:text="@string/confirm_income_amount" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/confrim_expnese_amount_TextView"
            style="@style/LightYellow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/confirm_income_item_TextView"
            android:gravity="right|center"
            android:text="@string/confirm_expnese_amount" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/up_down_imageButton"
            style="@style/UpDownButtonSelector"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="170dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/up_down_imageButton" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/save_percentage"
            style="@style/LightYellow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/balance_amount_TextView"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/heart_ImageView"
            android:gravity="left|center"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lbl_balance"
            style="@style/LightYellow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/confrim_expnese_amount_TextView"
            android:gravity="left|center"
            android:text="@string/usable_amount"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        **<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/heart_ImageView"
            style="@style/LightYellow"
            android:layout_width="260dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/lbl_balance"
            android:contentDescription="@string/heart_content" />**

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/balance_amount_TextView"
            style="@style/LightYellow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/lbl_balance_amount"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/lbl_balance_amount"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lbl_balance_amount"
            android:gravity="right|center"
            android:text="@string/balance_amount"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lbl_balance_amount"
            style="@style/LightYellow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/confrim_expnese_amount_TextView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lbl_balance"
            android:gravity="right|center"
            android:text="@string/lbl_balance_amount"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        **<View
            android:id="@+id/overlay"
            android:layout_width="260dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/lbl_balance" />**

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the source codes. I have marked the important codes with *.

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_buta_confirm, container, false);

        listRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) v
                .findViewById(R.id.fragment_list);
        int top = ((ButaColleTabBarActivity) getActivity())
                .getActionBarHeight() + 2;
        listRelativeLayout.setPadding(0, top, 0, 120);

        listLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.listlayout);
        listLinearLayout.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 160);

        ie_adapter = new Income_Expense_Adapter(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, butaColleList);

        view = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.datalist);
        view.setAdapter(ie_adapter);
        view.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                ButaColle butaColle = butaColleList.get(position);
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                ButaColleDetailIncomeExpenseFragment butaDetail = ButaColleDetailIncomeExpenseFragment
                        .newInstance(butaColle);

                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                        .beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.realTabContent, butaDetail);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("SearchFragment");
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });

        view.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
        view.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new MultiChoiceModeListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
                ie_adapter.removeSelection();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_delete_context, menu);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.menu_item_delete_data:
                    SparseBooleanArray selected = ie_adapter.getSelectedIds();
                    for (int i = (selected.size() - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
                        if (selected.valueAt(i)) {
                            ButaColle butaitem = ie_adapter.getItem(selected
                                    .keyAt(i));
                            dbhelper.deleteHistoryRecords(butaitem);
                            ie_adapter.remove(butaitem);
                        }
                    }
                    mode.finish();
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode,
                    int position, long id, boolean checked) {
                final int checkedCount = view.getCheckedItemCount();
                mode.setTitle(checkedCount + " Selected");
                ie_adapter.toggleSelection(position);
            }
        });

        updownImageButton = (ImageButton) v
                .findViewById(R.id.up_down_imageButton);
        updownImageButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.close01);
        updownImageButton.setTag(R.drawable.close01);
        updownImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (updownImageButton.getTag().equals((R.drawable.close01))) {
                    updownImageButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.open01);
                    updownImageButton.setTag(R.drawable.open01);
                    int top = ((ButaColleTabBarActivity) getActivity())
                            .getActionBarHeight() + 2;
                    listRelativeLayout.setPadding(0, top, 0, 50);
                    listLinearLayout.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 160);
                } else if (updownImageButton.getTag().equals(R.drawable.open01)) {
                    updownImageButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.close01);
                    updownImageButton.setTag(R.drawable.close01);
                    int top = ((ButaColleTabBarActivity) getActivity())
                            .getActionBarHeight() + 2;
                    listRelativeLayout.setPadding(0, top, 0, 120);
                    listLinearLayout.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 160);
                }
            }

        });

        int itemCount = 0;
        String itemlbl = "item";
        incomeItemcount_TextView = (TextView) v
                .findViewById(R.id.confirm_income_item_TextView);
        itemCount = dbhelper.getItemCount(1);
        if (itemCount > 1)
            itemlbl = "items";
        incomeItemcount_TextView.setText(String.valueOf(itemCount) + itemlbl);

        itemCount = 0;
        itemlbl = "item";
        expenseItemcount_TextView = (TextView) v
                .findViewById(R.id.confirm_expense_item_TextView);
        itemCount = dbhelper.getItemCount(0);
        if (itemCount > 1)
            itemlbl = "items";
        expenseItemcount_TextView.setText(String.valueOf(itemCount) + itemlbl);

        double balance = 0.0;
        double incomeAmount = 0.0;
        double expenseAmount = 0.0;
        incomeAmount_TextView = (TextView) v
                .findViewById(R.id.confirm_income_amount_TextView);
        incomeAmount = dbhelper.getTotalAmount(1);
        incomeAmount_TextView.setText(String.valueOf(incomeAmount) + "$");

        expenseAmount_TextView = (TextView) v
                .findViewById(R.id.confrim_expnese_amount_TextView);
        expenseAmount = dbhelper.getTotalAmount(0);
        expenseAmount_TextView.setText(String.valueOf(expenseAmount) + "$");

        balance = incomeAmount - expenseAmount;
        balance_TextView = (TextView) v
                .findViewById(R.id.balance_amount_TextView);
        balance_TextView.setText(String.valueOf(balance) + "$");

        int percentage = 0;
        percentage = (int) ((balance / incomeAmount) * 100);
        if (balance > 0) {
            heartImageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.heart_ImageView);
            heartImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.graph);
            percentage_TextView = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.save_percentage);
            percentage_TextView.setText(String.valueOf(percentage) + "%");
        } else {
            heartImageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.heart_ImageView);
            heartImageView.setImageResource(0);
            percentage_TextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(0);
            percentage = 0;
        }
        **View overlay = (View) v.findViewById(R.id.overlay);
        int opacity = 200; // from 0 to 255
        overlay.setBackgroundColor(opacity * 0x1000000); // black with a variable alpha
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params =
            new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(300, 36);
        overlay.setLayoutParams(params);
        overlay.invalidate();**
        return v;
    }
```

Please Help me to figure our.Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Changing

```
**<View
        android:id="@+id/overlay"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lbl_balance" />**
```

to

```
 **<View
            android:id="@+id/overlay"
            android:layout_width="260dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/heart_ImageView" />**
```

Changes made: layout alignment and the id of to whom it was aligned

Comment: Thanks Salvador G, your xml layout formation work well, but at run time, due to I have set **RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params =       new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(300, 36);     overlay.setLayoutParams(params);** so at run time the view move to up without being on the heart_ImageView, so finally I have added **params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);** and now the view is on heart_Imageview. Thanks buddy!

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding rules to the params with the addRule method

```
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
```

I'm not near my PC to test, but you may be able to set the view below `lbl_balance` with the addRule method

Or, try removing the layout params in the code all together. The xml inflates the view, so it is already created. All you need to do in code is set the background color. Which you can also do in the xml with

```
android:background="#80000000"
```

Comment: Thanks jb15613, I have added in source code like **params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);** so now the view does not move to top in its layout. The view now lies on top of ImageView in its layout. I am sorry I couldn't give you correct answer because the above one answer already work too and your codes too. I used your source code and Salvador G layout source code. Thank you buddy. :)